# ugly launcher icon for smartgit

Tags: launcher, icons

When I open smartgit via the terminal i get this weird looking icon with a question mark in my launcher. When i go "add to launcher", close smartgit again and try to open it via the launcher, nothing happens.

Comment: i did it in /usr/bin because "which smartgit" told me that its located there.

Comment: That seems to be the problem. The application can't find the icons. Start it in the originally folder and it will work. How have you installed smartgit?

Comment: like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13853924/1699932

Comment: I have removed the output of your `ls` command. Makes no sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said in your comments, you used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13853924/1699932) answer and therefore the PPA `ppa:eugenesan/ppa`, but you **should not** use it:

> Packages in this a nd related PPAs are for personal use only.   They
>   developed specifically for several custom environments and may not
>   work for you.

To check your problem I have installed the PPA and had some unpleasant side effects.

**Therefore purge the PPA** via

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:eugenesan/ppa
```

and install `smartgit` via the steps below

- Download the latest version [here](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/download)

  [image]

  either the `deb` file or the `tar.gz`, the result is the same

Now you have to decide. Use the `deb` or the `tar.gz`

### Use the `deb` file

- Install the `deb` file via

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i smartgit-7_0_0.de
  ```

### or

### Use the `tar.gz` file

1. Extract the archive in `/opt`

   ```
   sudo tar xf smartgit-generic-7_0_0.tar.gz -C /opt
   ```
2. Install the desktop file with the command

   ```
   /opt/smartgit/bin/add-menuitem.sh
   ```

---

That's all

Start SmartGit via your Launcher, in my screenshoot GNOME Shell

[image]

---

You can check for updates in SmartGit via

<kbd>Help</kbd> > <kbd>Check for new Version ...</kbd>

[image]

***;)***

Comment: thanks for your in-detail explanaition. in the end i managed to get it running the way you suggested. i have actually already tried it that way before i used ppa. the trick to get it working now, was to run remove-menuitem.sh before i run add-menuitem.sh. thx! :)